# Should subject alternative name displayed by openssl utility?

Tags: security, openssl, certificates, pfsense

I am using the following web-ui to generate certificates in pfSense:

[image]

I was thinking to generate a certificate, suitable for serving from multiple domains, prelimilarly from `localhost` and `nebula3`.

Was this correct idea?

Unfortunately, when I am inspecting generated certificate with `openssl` I see the following

```
# openssl x509 -noout -subject -in nebula3.crt
subject= /C=RU/ST=Moscow/L=Moscow/O=In The Moon Network/emailAddress=dims12@mail.ru/CN=nebula3
```

i.e. I see only one `CN` field and no `SAN` fields.

Does this definitely mean `pfSense` has a bug in web-interface or I should watch somewhere else?

Comment: I am using the last version of pfSense and I too think it is not suitable to generate certificates as I need them. I would advise generating the CSR and the certificate offline, and feeding it to pfSense. Do you need help with that?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro would be appreciated! I wrote a qstn here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324678/the-certificate-is-not-valid-for-the-name-localhost

Comment: Per your other Q, SAN is not part of Subject and is not displayed by `-subject`. Use `-text` and look under `X509v3 Extensions`.

Comment: What's the status of this now. I'm trying to do the same thing

Answer (score 0):

As for certificates generated by pfSense, I have been dealing with them recently, and gave up using them on the context of a VPN server.

Basically when signing VPN certificates, I use this extra atributes:

```
[ v3_req ]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment

subjectAltName = DNS:youralternanetname.uk, IP:193.x.x.x, DNS:193.x.x.x
nsCertType                      = server
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth, 1.3.6.1.5.5.8.2.2
keyUsage = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
```

It seems Windows clients need to see the IP address of your VPN server in the certificate.

You also need to add to the openssl command line CSR request the option: `-extensions v3_req` or otherwise it won't show up in `-noout`because it probably is not there.

As for loading my certificates in pfSense, I do:

System->Cert. Manager->Certificates->+Add->Important an existing Certificate. Beware the actual certificate there should contain the entire X.509 certificate chain.