# The certificate is not valid for the name localhost

Tags: openssl, certificates

I am trying to generate a certificate for serving both from `localhost` and other names

I used the following commands

```
openssl genrsa -out nebula3.key 1024
openssl req -key nebula3.key -new -out nebula3.req -subj '/C=RU/ST=Moscow/L=Moscow/O=In The Moon Network/OU=/CN=nebula3/emailAddress=dims12@mail.ru/subjectAltName=DNS.1=localhost,DNS.2=nebula3.inthemoon.net'
openssl x509 -req -in nebula3.req -CA In+The+Moon+Authority.crt -CAkey In+The+Moon+Authority.key -CAserial file.srl -out nebula3.pem
```

Files `In The Moon Authority.crt` and `In The Moon Authority.key` are my own generated and self-signed CA.

Now I got certificate with

```
# openssl x509 -noout -subject -in nebula3.pem
subject= /C=RU/ST=Moscow/L=Moscow/O=In The Moon Network/CN=nebula3/emailAddress=dims12@mail.ru/subjectAltName=DNS.1=localhost,DNS.2=nebula3.inthemoon.net
```

unfortunately, when I am trying to serve with this certificate from `localhost` I get the following error

[image]

looks like Firefox doesn't like this certificate although it has `localhost` in alternative names.

May be I put incorrect SAN type? I see `DNS` here, which looks like type. What are other types possible and what is theis syntax?

In some web-ui I saw the following 4 types:

[image]

How can I specify them in command line? May be I could use `IP`?

Comment: SubjectAlternativeName must be an extension, NOT part of (an 'attribute' in) the Subject field; see http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/74345/provide-subjectaltname-to-openssl-directly-on-command-line

Comment: certificates accept only FQDN....would localhost. (with the period) help? I would not add localhost to a X.509 certificate.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 what does it mean `-config <(cat /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf <(printf "[SAN]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:example.com,DNS:www.example.com"))` in Linux?

Comment: @Rob this implies HTTPS can't be used with `localhost`, which can't be true

Comment: That method is actually more complex than needed. `cat /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf <(printf ...)` means run the `printf` command given then run `cat` and give it as arguments the filename `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` and a filename that reads the output from the `printf`; since cat outputs the concatenation of the files named by its arguments, this produces an output consisting of the contents of `/etc/ssl/openssl.conf` followed by the output produced by the `printf` command which here is an OpenSSL config section for a SAN extension.`<(cat ...)` then passes `openssl -config` a filename that reads ...

Comment: ... the output from the `cat` which (on systems where `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` is in fact the 'normal' OpenSSL config file) contains the config file contents needed for the `openssl req` command given there to generate a request containing SAN extension. This could be done simpler by `<(cat /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf; printf "[SAN]\netc etc ")`

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: _certs_ require only a hostname, which can be relative or implicit as here, or a wildcard name (leftmost element only), or an IP address. _Public CAs_ (and in particular members of the CA/Browser forum) require names registered under the public DNS root, which are necessarily FQDNs, or a wildcard (not directly under a TLD or reserved 2LD like co.uk), and optionally publicly-routable IP addresses.